# Rails: How to speficy different sources for gemfile when in development/production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in China. So I need to change the source to `source 'http://ruby.taobao.org/'`
But I push it to heroku, and heroku only support `source 'https://rubygems.org'`

Can I do something like

```
group :development do
  source 'http://ruby.taobao.org/'
end
group :production do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
end
```

Or what is the corret way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gem file is correct but you need to change the way you execute the bundler since it doesn't know about Rails and the current environment.

To install in the production environment:

```
  bundle install --without development
```

To install in the development environment:

```
  bundle install --without production
```

Comment: Does `group :development` is content is lef empty by intention?

Comment: @cqcn1991 no, I was following OP's example

Comment: I don't have specific gems to put into `production` of `development`. Actually, I need the different `source` for every gem, how can I do that?

Comment: The gems can be the same. Heroku is going to use the gems within the production group, which is enclosed in the rubygems.org source

Comment: No, no, no. I mean if I want to add a new gem, then I have to add it twice. That means, I need to **maitain 2 same list at the same time**. That's tiresome. Is there a way I can store the whole gem list in a variable and then declared them in `source do` block?

Comment: @cqcn1991 I see. I've updated the answer. Untested but I think it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer anymore. If I set the Gemfile to be like the question above and then run bundle the way you mention, I get a bundler deprecation warning about using multiple sources. Any idea if there's a new proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is to nest certain gems within a source

```
group :development do
  source 'http://ruby.taobao.org/' do
    gem1
    gem2
  end
end
```